# get previous and next id from customly ordered and filtered table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

In my PHP/mysql application user can filter and order records from database. Filter can be set for each column separatly and order can be set for each column DESC/ASC. He gets a table where he can click to detail one record and in detail is previous and next button witch brinbgs him to next/previous record with respect to filter and order he set up at table.

Is any way to get id of next and previous record when table is ordered by column where can be duplicit values? I've tried something like this:

```
select * from foo where column = (select min(column) from foo where column > 4)
```

But that doesn't work for records where previous column value is same as current.

Because of that a table can have several milions of records, I can't just select all and iterate throught whole table.

Comment: Is this a question about pagination?

Comment: pagination here does't matter. Just need id of previous and next record

Comment: I have just one record from ordered and filtered set and need to get id of next and previous record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, this *dirty* thing might be helpful:

1. First of all, you may write your SELECT query like this:

   ```
   SET @row_num=0;
   SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS `row_num`, t_table.* FROM t_table WHERE type_id>0 ORDER BY type_id ASC, type_place_id DESC, user_id DESC LIMIT 100;
   ```

Point here is to get an order number of each row (will be present in column `row_num`).

2. The second step is to save row_num value of clicked record ($current).
3. So to get data about current record, you may use next query:

   ```
   SET @row_num=0;
   SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS `row_num`, t_table.* FROM t_table WHERE type_id>0 ORDER BY type_id ASC, type_place_id DESC, user_id DESC LIMIT 100) AS counted_view WHERE counted_view.row_num = {$current};
   ```

About previous:

```
    SET @row_num=0;
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS `row_num`, t_table.* FROM t_table WHERE type_id>0 ORDER BY type_id ASC, type_place_id DESC, user_id DESC LIMIT 100) AS counted_view WHERE counted_view.row_num = {$current - 1};
```

Next record:

```
SET @row_num=0;
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT @row_num:=@row_num+1 AS `row_num`, t_table.* FROM t_table WHERE type_id>0 ORDER BY type_id ASC, type_place_id DESC, user_id DESC LIMIT 100) AS counted_view WHERE counted_view.row_num = {$current + 1};
```